# jQuery: How do I obtain specific subsets of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

I have to display a table on a web page, which is subsequently printed. The table rows are retrieved by this statement:

```
var rows = $element.find(".row");
```

Say this results in 50 rows. Now the requirements are:

- there should be 20 rows per printed page
- each printed page must display the column headers, which are in `rows[0]` and `rows[1]`

Therefore I need to loop through the `rows` collection so that the loop gives me the right subset per page, like this:

```
var printRows = rows.slice(0, 2) + rows.slice(2, 22); //values for page 1
var printRows = rows.slice(0, 2) + rows.slice(22, 42); //values for page 2
var printRows = rows.slice(0, 2) + rows.slice(42, 52); //values for page 3
```

I know how to create the loop. The problem is that these lines are not valid jQuery. How can I obtain the subsets of rows that I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you would want to slice the data into pages before it's added to the page. But if you're doing it this way, the issue is that you're trying to `+` two arrays (of jQuery objects) together, which isn't going to give you the expected result. (Check out other ways to join arrays, e.g. [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), or [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although jQuery objects aren't really arrays, they can be used as if they are, both with `slice` as you already did, and using the [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (spread) operator.

Here is an example using `slice` and `...` to get the items that you need. It uses an array, but will also work with a jQuery object containing DOM elements.

```js
const pageLength = 20;
const pageCount = 5;
const rows = [];
while (rows.length < pageCount * pageLength - 10) rows.push(rows.length);

for (let page = 1; page <= pageCount; page++) {
  var result = [
    ...rows.slice(0, 2),
    ...rows.slice(2 + (page - 1) * pageLength, 2 + page * pageLength)
  ];
  console.log("Page " + page + ":", result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. I didn't know about the spread operator. Thank you!